# "sudo perf script -g python" command resulting in segmentation fault in RHEL8.2 linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, profiling, redhat, perf

I am new to working with "perf" tool, exploring perf script with python capabilities.

I have generated `perf.data` with following command

```
(pft) [csaraiya@localhost Desktop]$ sudo perf sched record -- sleep 1

[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ] 
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.548 MB perf.data (34 samples) ]
```

Following are the verbose logs...

```
sudo perf script -g python -v 

 
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_cfg80211.so 
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_function.so 
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_hrtimer.so 
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_jbd2.so 
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_kmem.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_kvm.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_mac80211.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_sched_switch.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_scsi.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_xen.so
overriding event (314) sched:sched_wakeup with new print handler
overriding event (313) sched:sched_wakeup_new with new print handler
overriding event (312) sched:sched_switch with new print handler
build id event received for [kernel.kallsyms]: 775af45c3e14e58702909dda76>
build id event received for [vdso]: 2989a6ff69be8af0b0edc2bc57919c3fc1ef1>
**(END)Segmentation fault**

sudo perf buildid-list -v  perf.data
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_cfg80211.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_function.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_hrtimer.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_jbd2.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_kmem.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_kvm.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_mac80211.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_sched_switch.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_scsi.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_xen.so
overriding event (314) sched:sched_wakeup with new print handler
overriding event (313) sched:sched_wakeup_new with new print handler
overriding event (312) sched:sched_switch with new print handler
build id event received for [kernel.kallsyms]: 775af45c3e14e58702909dda76>
build id event received for [vdso]: 2989a6ff69be8af0b0edc2bc57919c3fc1ef1>
775af45c3e14e58702909dda765d6143dbf57d8f [kernel.kallsyms]
2989a6ff69be8af0b0edc2bc57919c3fc1ef1f87 [vdso]


sudo perf buildid-list -v --with-hits  perf.data
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_cfg80211.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_function.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_hrtimer.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_jbd2.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_kmem.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_kvm.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_mac80211.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_sched_switch.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_scsi.so
registering plugin: /usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/plugin_xen.so
overriding event (314) sched:sched_wakeup with new print handler
overriding event (313) sched:sched_wakeup_new with new print handler
overriding event (312) sched:sched_switch with new print handler
build id event received for [kernel.kallsyms]: 775af45c3e14e58702909dda76>
build id event received for [vdso]: 2989a6ff69be8af0b0edc2bc57919c3fc1ef1>
Using /proc/kcore for kernel data
Using /proc/kallsyms for symbols
775af45c3e14e58702909dda765d6143dbf57d8f /proc/kcore



(pft) [csaraiya@localhost ~]$ uname -r 
4.18.0-193.14.3.el8_2.x86_64

Python 3.6.8 

[csaraiya@localhost ~]$ perf --version 
perf version 4.18.0-193.14.3.el8_2.x86_64
```

I have tried by downloading perf from  link  specified in comment and recompiled it .
.

```
with kernel-5.0.0-37-generic
```

with following gdb logs

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62
62  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62
#1  0x00007ffff66c4563 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=s@entry=0x555555dffd70, 
    format=format@entry=0x555555a0f5b7 "def %s__%s(", 
    ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffbb90) at vfprintf.c:1643
#2  0x00007ffff6799676 in ___fprintf_chk (fp=fp@entry=0x555555dffd70, 
    flag=flag@entry=1, format=format@entry=0x555555a0f5b7 "def %s__%s(")
    at fprintf_chk.c:35
#3  0x0000555555852b1c in fprintf (__fmt=0x555555a0f5b7 "def %s__%s(", 
    __stream=0x555555dffd70) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:97
#4  python_generate_script (pevent=0x555555df2b70, outfile=<optimized out>)
    at util/scripting-engines/trace-event-python.c:1642
#5  0x000055555572760a in cmd_script (argc=<optimized out>, 
    argv=<optimized out>) at builtin-script.c:3673
#6  0x0000555555776e51 in run_builtin (p=0x555555c7e6d8 <commands+408>, 
    argc=4, argv=0x7fffffffe590) at perf.c:302
#7  0x000055555577715e in handle_internal_command (argc=4, argv=0x7fffffffe590)
    at perf.c:354
#8  0x00005555556f4a11 in run_argv (argcp=<synthetic pointer>, 
    argv=<synthetic pointer>) at perf.c:398
#9  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7fffffffe590) at perf.c:520
(gdb)
```

Comment: It looks sane to me and works on my Arch Linux system. This would be something I'd report as a bug to the distribution shipping perf. You might get better results, or insight into the bug, by compiling `perf` yourself from the Linux kernel code (you just need build `tools/perf`, not the entire kernel).

Comment: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/ has source archives needed to rebuild various versions of perf (newer version of perf should be able to read perf.data from older version). Rebuilding `perf` tool with debug information and checking stacktrace of SIGSEGV with gdb may be useful (`sudo gdb --args perf script -g python -v`; then `run`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Zulan and osgx ..following is bt in gdb..```Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff56d7655 in __strlen_avx2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff56d7655 in __strlen_avx2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff55cc43f in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff56854ca in __fprintf_chk () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00005555558d777c in ?? ()
#4  0x00005555557a8ca2 in cmd_script ()
#5  0x00005555557fd74d in ?? ()
#6  0x000055555577496a in main ()```

Comment: Hi osgx  .. I have updated My Question with Extra logs with kernel version ```kernel-5.0.0-37-generic ``` ,. I have Build perf on my Ubuntu machine ...I am getting same Segmentation fault ..Can you check and let me know what are the further steps. Or if I am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Check the first page of output of your perf build. There are some compilation flags listed there, is there `libpython: [ on  ]` string? Which perf version did you compile?

Comment: I have the same issue on my Ubuntu system 5.15.0-60-generic
and perf coming from my linux-tools package with version 5.15.0-60.
This happens to me when I add `perf inject  -s` between my `perf record` and `perf script` command.